# javascript - stopping global functionality

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a legacy application and I found this javascript snippet:

```
function keypress(e) {
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event; 
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 9:case 13: {
        ...
        }
```

This has been working great, however I have added new functionality to the application using a specific function that is called from the `onKeyPress` of a `<div>`, lets call it `function xyz()`.  This function works great except when the enter key is pressed.  In my new function I can capture the keycode 13 (the enter key), but I can not stop it from going to this function above.  When the Enter key is pressed in my new functionality the code above causes it to error.

I need a way to prevent the Enter key from going to the `keypress(e)` function (above).  Is there a way I can stop it from doing this.

```
function xyz(event)
{
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
      //  I need to stop the process of the Enter key here
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript function redefinition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227222/javascript-function-redefinition)

Comment: @Marc - I looked at that question and I'm not sure how that is a similar question.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, can you clarify it? Why can't you just change the quoted code?

Comment: @JeffV: you said "override", which to me means replace the original function with something new. Hence "redefine".

Comment: @Marc - I see where you are going with that.  Basically I still need that old functionality but I also need to add new functionality so that is why I used override (in .Net you can use the override key word that allows the same function name to be called with different signatures).  That is why I used the word override.

Comment: Problem in JS is that you can only replace the function, you can't have the same function name with two different bodies. If you redefine the function for your new code, you might break the legacy code using it. How about just creating a new "newKeyPress()" function that does what you want?

Comment: This function is a global function on the included js file.  I have a specific keypress function that is working for the up/down arrow keys but since the enter key is defined in this function already it is defaulting to the one above.  That is why I was looking to somehow "Override" that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should be entirely unobtrusive, just tested something similar:

```
new function() {
    var old_kp = window.keypress;
    delete window.keypress;
    window.keypress = function(e) {
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 13: /* do your thing */
            default: {
                return old_kp(e);
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

You can call the function the same way as before, it wraps the old function and in cases other than '13' you just delegate to the old implementation.

---

Edit:

To cancel the propagation of the 'Enter' key event, have a look at the section [Turning it off](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). It will tell you how you can prevent propagation in a cross-browser-compatible way:

```
function xyz(e) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       if (!e) var e = window.event;
       e.cancelBubble = true;
       if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Old versions of IE do not pass an event to the event handler, you need to retrieve window.event instead. That's why we first check whether e has been assigned - if not, we assign window.event to e. The cancelBubble property is also IE-specific, setting it will do the trick for IE and other browsers won't complain, they simply overlook the property. The final check is whether the method stopPropagation exists for the event. stopPropagation is the solution recommended by the W3C event model. All modern browsers support this (including IE 9). Using this code you will cover all existing possibilities for stopping event propagation in all more or less modern browsers.

Comment: you switched from event to e.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Sorry, no, just wanted to save some typing :)

Comment: so should e be event?  as my function is xyz(event,foo)

Comment: once I got the variable names situated, then it worked!  Thank you!  Is there anyway you can explain what exactly this solution is doing?  For example what does !event do?  I'm assuming the window.event is the current keypress.  If you could update your answer it would help me and others understand it more.  Thanks for sticking around to help me.

Comment: I added a few words, but I'm almost sure that the original article does a better job in explaining the details.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should something like:

```
function keypress(e) {
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event; 
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 9: {
        ...}
        break;
        case 13: ...//your code
        break;
        }
```

Comment: I need the old code for the enter key to function the same way, however, I need the enter key to behave differently for this new functionality.  How can I override this function?

Comment: I rewrote the question to better clarify the needs of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just make the event listener listen to your function first, and then call `keypress`?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are asking, you should be able to just separate the "Enter" case in the [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement, as shown:

```
function keypress(e) {
    var evt = (e) ? e : window.event; 
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 9:
            //Tab Key Pressed
             break;

        case 13: 
            //Enter Key Pressed
            break;
     }
}
```

In order to stop the execution in keypress, you could check what key was pressed prior to the switch statement, or just `return false` inside the case 13:

```
function keypress(e) {
        var evt = (e) ? e : window.event; 
        if(evt.keyCode != 13)
        {
            switch (evt.keyCode) {
                case 9:
                    //Tab Key Pressed
                    break;

                case 13: 
                    //Enter Key Pressed
                    break;
            }
        }
   }
```

or

```
function keypress(e) {
        var evt = (e) ? e : window.event; 
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 9:
                //Tab Key Pressed
                 break;

            case 13: 
                return false;
                break;
         }
    }
```