# Completely remove Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a website that has a fixed menu, header, etc. and loads the main content area via AJAX based on the menu clicks.
These "pages" rely on a lot of Javascript and CSS which are individual for each page. Since a user can potentially visit many pages, I want to unload the page-specific JS and CSS. The CSS was straight-forward, but removing the `<script>` tags does not remove the loaded Javascript (I can still call functions defined in it).
How can I really "remove" the JS? I don't want the memory overhead, or to have to worry about name clashes between pages.

Comment: So is your site really just one page that loads data from other pages dynamically when the user clicks the menu items? What JavaScript are you wanting to remove exactly? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Properly modularized JavaScript shouldn't suffer from problems like this--keep page-specific JavaScript inside a page-specific module.

Comment: You can't remove javascript from memory. That's the browser's job.

Comment: Load your functions into a page specific object. Ditch the object when you are done with it (assign all variables (hopefully just one) that point to it to null or w/e). Make calls through that object. Just an idea.

Comment: @trinithis Great idea! I would mark it as the answer if it was one (instead of a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your functions into a page specific object. This will require you to make all your page specific calls though that object. When you want to unload the page, make that object point to something else (say null). Now you don't have references to the object, and it will be cleaned up by the runtime. (Assume nobody else points to it. This is trivial to enforce.)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (from [this post on Perfection Kills](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)) is that you can only completely remove javascript function declarations if they were created using eval(). If that is the case, you can remove the function by calling

```
delete funcName;
```

If the function was not created using eval(), the best you can do is redefine it.  There are numerous examples of that.  Here's one: [javascript function redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3227222/1024576)